# Fill text in webform with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I want to write a scraper with Selenium.
But the login doesn't work.

The code I used:

```
    login_form = self.driver.find_element_by_id("login_form")
    username_form = login_form.find_element_by_id("login")
    password_form = login_form.find_element_by_id("password")

    username, password = self.get_credentials()
    username_form.send_keys(username)
    password_form.send_keys(password)
    login_form.submit()
```

But the login doesn't work, because the password is wrong. I debugged it and discovered that in the variable the password is correct, but another password is entered in the browser.

By the way my password contains special characters, like circumflex (^).

Comment: "browser another password is incoming" and how is that password compared to the content of `password`?

Comment: there are no circumflexes

Comment: ok. there are a lot of more characters which are not sent to the browser. I found ^`´°. Is this intended or a bug?

Comment: If this is Python 2, then issue might be related to handling of unicode characters. You might [dive](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) [deep](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) or switch to Python 3. I would recommend the second solution.

Comment: I'm not sure if the misbehaviour is related to the handling of unicode characters. If I send the string "Ä" an error is appearing, but as unicode string u"Ä" I can send the string. But when I tried to send "^" or u"^" no error is appearing and nothing is send.
But yes I'm using Python 2 and I will try it in Python 3

Comment: Ok it seems to be a bug of chromedriver, because with the geckodriver it works with firefox.